# The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I was learning firebase to integrate with my react web app. I was trying to write functions for GET and POST requests and running them on postman using endpoints i get in my terminal in vscode.
Now my code works perfectly with firebase deploy but gives me errors with i try using firebase serve. also i cannot just use these commands simply , i have to run them using sudo and then enter my password and only then i'm able to run them.
below is the error list

> The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
>
> ⚠  External network resource requested!
>      - URL: "http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance"
>    - Be careful, this may be a production service.
>
> ⚠  External network resource requested!
>      - URL: "http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance"
>    - Be careful, this may be a production service.
>
> Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
>
> ```
>  at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/home/nikunj/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:160:19)
>
>  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
>
>  at async GoogleAuth.getClient (/home/nikunj/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:502:17)
>
>  at async GrpcClient._getCredentials (/home/nikunj/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:92:24)
>
>  at async GrpcClient.createStub (/home/nikunj/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js:213:23)
> ```
>
> Caused by: Error
>
> ```
>  at WriteBatch.commit (/home/nikunj/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:415:23)
>
>  at DocumentReference.create (/home/nikunj/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:283:14)
>  at CollectionReference.add (/home/nikunj/socialape-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:2011:28)
>  at /home/nikunj/socialape-functions/functions/index.js:32:10
>  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:559:20
>  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:534:19
>  at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
>  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:8:71
>  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>  at __awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:4:12)
> ```
>
> i  functions: Finished "createScream" in ~1s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i actually solved this by  giving in the credentials using service account in firebase project setting. i changed my intialise app to

````
    var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

    admin.initializeApp({
     credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
     databaseURL: "https://socialape-6925b.firebaseio.com"
     });```
````

Answer (score 3):

For me the missing step was that I had not initialized the firestore emulator using

```
firebase init emulators
```

Comment: I still don't understand how this stuff works all i do is check for solutions online and try and understand what changes could help me out :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes I also got the same error but I solve this.

First , make sure you have .firebaserc file in your project folder
then initialize the admin  using:-

```
admin.initializeApp();
```